# how to capture the http status code from service callout in Apigee

Tags: apigee

Please let me know how to capture the HTTP status code received from a 3rd party invoke using Service Callout policy. I need this to do some conditional checks in flow.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got it with some experimentation

```
context.getVariable("calloutResponse.status.code");
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Your the response object is defined in the Callout policy -- by default ApigeeUI uses calloutResponse, but good convention is to rename it to something more informative and less likely to get overwritten.

So, if you named it, for example, "yahooWeather" you could then access the variable "yahooWeather.status.code".